# swift - how to define an indirect enum case of a specific type

Tags: swift, enums

I want to define an `enum` representing a simplified version of a `markdown` document

I want something like the following but don't understand the syntax for defining the indirect enumerations

```
enum Markdown {
case text(String)
case sourceCode(code: String, language: Language)
indirect case tableCell(either "text" or "sourceCode")
indirect case tableRow(only table cells allowed)
indirect case table(only tableRow allowed)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Due to the [documentation](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Enumerations.html#ID536) indirect enums can only refer to itself. A finer granularity is not possible. Your declaration should loo like

```
enum Markdown {
    case text(String)
    case sourceCode(code: String, language: String)
    indirect case tableCell(Markdown)
    indirect case tableRow([Markdown])
    indirect case table([Markdown])
}

let t = Markdown.text("Hello")
let c = Markdown.tableCell(t)
```

You may also put the `indirect` keyword in front of the enum declaration to avoid its repetition:

```
indirect enum Markdown {
    case text(String)
    case sourceCode(code: String, language: String)
    case tableCell(Markdown)
    case tableRow([Markdown])
    case table([Markdown])
}
```

You may define more type-safe enums:

```
indirect enum Content {
    case text(String)
    case bold(Content)
    case italic(Content)
    case span([Content])
}
indirect enum TableRow {
    case tableCells([Content])
}
```

etc.

But I think that this leads very fast to other problems and you should rather work with structs or classes.

Comment: this could lead to tables cells inside cells which isn't valid right?

Comment: Yes, you could avoid this by multiple enums. I will add an example.